# Ошибка в процессе выполнения (limb.so.6)

Tags: python

Я решала задачу, написала к ней код, в редакторе кода VS Code все работает, никаких ошибок в процессе исполнения нет, но как только вставляю код на учебную платформу, появляется ошибка связанная с limb.so.6

Условие задачи: У каждого спортсмена индивидуальный номер. Спортсмены выходят из раздевалки и должны построиться в шеренгу. Тренер каждому выходящему называет номер. Выходящий должен встать после этого спортсмена, а если его нет, то в начало.
Входные данные:
Сначала задано натуральное число n <= 100000, кол-во спортсменов. Далее идут n пар неотрицательных чисел, 1-е - выходящий спортсмен, 2-е - после кого должен встать.
Выходные данные:
Напечатать номера спортсменов после построения.

Вот сам код:

```
n = int(input())
N = []
N_copy = []
for i in range(n):
  pr, past = map(int, input().split())
  if past in N_copy:
    index = N.index(past) + 1
    N_1 = N[0:index]
    N_2 = N[index:-1]
    N_1.append(pr)
    N = N_1 + N_2
    N_copy.append(pr)
  else:
    M = N[ : :-1]
    M.append(pr)
    N = M[ : :-1]
    N_copy.append(pr)
for i in N:
  print(i)
```

Проверила все функции и методы, нет ничего необычного, во всех остальных программах все функции и методы работают.
Помогите, пожалуйста, найти, где возникает ошибка в процессе выполнения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
n = int(input())
list_2 = []

for _ in range(n):
    number_1, number_2 = input().split()
    if number_2 not in list_2:
        list_2.insert(0, number_1)
    else:
        list_2.insert(list_2.index(number_2) + 1, number_1)

print(*list_2, sep="\n")
```

Проходит?

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]